# Filter data from JSON file according to JSON array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I would like to filter my JSON array according to JSON array. I have following JSON array.

```
$scope.datas = [
    {"value": "1", "text": "aaa"},
    {"value": "2", "text": "bbb"},
    {"value": "3", "text": "ccc"},
    {"value": "4", "text": "ddd"},
    {"value": "5", "text": "eee"},
    {"value": "6", "text": "fff"},
    {"value": "7", "text": "ggg"},
    {"value": "8", "text": "hhh"},
    {"value": "9", "text": "iii"},
    {"value": "10", "text": "jjj"}
];
```

I want to filter this data according to my next JSON array.

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,3,9"};
```

This array can be change with same format.

Example 1:

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,3,9"}
```

Example 2:

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,7"}
```

Example 3:

```
$scope.array = {"badge":"1,2,5,7,8,9"}
```

I want to filter datas JSON array according to array of badge.

Display HTML body only

aaa bbb eee ggg

My code is working but older IE are not working because of it has find function.

```
$http.get("datas.json").success(function(data) {
$scope.spitedata = response.data.badge.split(',');
$scope.badgers = $scope.spitedata.map(function(o){ return data.find(function(k){return k.value == o})});
});
```

Comment: not hard to add a polyfill for `find()` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Comment: This code is work but I want a code for old IE browser support code.

Comment: Why do someone dislike this post?

Comment: A *"polyfill"* is used to support older browsers and the one you need is shown in docs link above

Comment: $scope.badgers = $scope.spitedata.map(function(o){ return data.prototype.find(function(k){return k.value == o})}); I add like this but not working

Comment: Please give me better solution for old IE browser support.

Comment: Use the polyfill shown in the docs